# Node JS cookie management

Tags: node.js

Having some trouble managing cookies with axios using node js. I am trying to collect some data from a website but, in order to do this, I first have to send a post request which logs me in and sends me a cookie. I have accomplished this and I can see the login successful and the cookie sent back to me (set-cookie confirms this with console log), but then need to send another request through a get request for information. Which doesn't work indicating not authorised which believe is because didn't accept the cookie for subsequent calls to keep the session alive. I'm not using browser just doing this through terminal, is this possible with node js?

Comment: The client needs to put the received cookie in the subsequent requests. The browser does that automatically for you but if you send the requests by other means (curl, Postman, telnet, your own code, etc) then you have to take care of this explicitly.

Comment: if you are using termnial, then you have to set [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header with cookie sent by your server previously.